# Insert annotations using XeTeX and BibTeX / BibLaTeX in MacTeX 2012

Tags: bibtex, xetex, mactex

I have the following problem. My `.tex` file (see below) works in MacTeX 2011 without problems (build it using XeLaTeX => BibTeX => XeLaTeX). After I updated from MacTeX 2011 to MacTeX 2012 it doesn't work. During build I get the following error in console.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: ABook.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ABook.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ABook.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ABook.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

My `.tex` file is the following :

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{metalogo}       
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Palatino}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\newcommand*{\annotecite}[1]{\citefield{#1}{annotation} \autocite{#1}}
\bibliography{NaWiLibrary}
\begin{document}
\enquote{\annotecite{MikrobiologieBrock}}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My example entry in the `.bib`  (BibTeX) file is the following :

```
@book{MikrobiologieBrock,
    Annote = {Kapitel 1, Seite 8, Zusammenfassung ... 
},
    Author = {Michael T. Madigan, John M. Martinko},
    Date-Added = {2012-11-10 13:55:04 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2012-11-14 08:59:46 +0000},
    Edition = {11., aktualisierte Auflage 2009},
    Isbn = {978-3-8273-7358-8},
    Pages = {1248},
    Publisher = {Pearson Studium},
    Title = {Brock Mikrobiologie},
    Url = {http://www.pearson-studium.de/main/main.asp?page=bookdetails&ProductID=169347},
    Year = {12 / 2008},
    Bdsk-Url-1 = {http://www.pearson-studium.de/main/main.asp?page=bookdetails&ProductID=169347}}
```

Has someone a idea how to fix this ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MacTeX 2012 you have a recent version of `biblatex` (version > 2.0), while in MacTeX you  have a version < 2.0.  With with a version of `biblatex` > 2.0 the default backend is `biber` and no longer `bibtex`.  Thus you have two options, compile the bibliography with `biber` or add `backend=bibtex` to the option of `biblatex`.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution. I found no detail informations because the `texdoc biblatex` command in terminal brings the pdf of version 1.6. Only if you look in the TeX Live Utility you get the pdf of version 2.5. I decided to use `backend=bibtex` and changed the line to `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,style=authoryear]{biblatex}`.

Comment: @NaWiatMac you can use `texdoc -l bib latex.pdf` to list all versions of the pdf. You might have an old version of biblatex somewehre in your TeX environment.

Comment: Nope, there is no other file because it was a clean install on a new MacBook with Mountain Lion. After I used `texdoc biblatex` again, I saw in Preview that the translation (I run a german system) was opened. `texdoc -l biblatex-de.pdf` and `texdoc -l biblatex.pdf` show´s me that the biblatex.pdf was version 2.5 and the biblatex-de.pdf was version 1.6. I reported that by email to the MacTeX team.